# How to determine the radius of a particular hypersphere?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, geometry

I am considering the equation
$$
(\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{x}_0)' \mathbf{J}_0'\mathbf{J}_0(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}_0) = c^2,
$$
where $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^m$ is a vector of coordinates, $\mathbf{x}_0 \in \mathbb{R}^m$ is a fixed point, $\mathbf{J}_0 \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times m}$ is a constant matrix and $c \in \mathbb{R}$ is a strictly positive constant.  $\mathbf{J}_0$ is the Jacobian matrix of an arbitrary system of functions $\mathbf{f(\mathbf{x})}:\mathbb{R}^m \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ evaluated at $\mathbf{x}_0$.

By writing the above as
$$
||\mathbf{J}_0(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}_0)||_2^2 = c^2,
$$
or otherwise, I would like to conclude that the solution describes a hypershpere centred on $\mathbf{x}_0$ and with a radius which can be inferred.

My questions are therefore:

1. Is it true that the solution describes a hypersphere?
2. If so, what is its radius?

Comment: (i) Do primes denote transposing? (ii) If $J_0$ an orthogonal matrix?

Comment: (i) Yes $\mathbf{A}' := \mathbf{A}^T$.  (ii) No, $\mathbf{J}_0$ cannot be guaranteed to be orthogonal. 

I've updated the question to include more detail on $\mathbf{J}_0$.

Comment: If $J_0$ is nonsingular (invertible), then you'll get an ellipsoid. However, if $J_0$ is singular, you'll get a generalized cylinder. No radius makes sense here. You can think of this quadric hypersurface as $x^\top A x = c$, where $A$ is a positive semidefinite symmetric matrix. Its eigenvalues will determine the semi-axes of the ellipsoid.

Comment: Thank you @TedShifrin, I was literally just now reading up about the possibility that this might be describing an ellipsoid rather than a hypersphere.  For all but degenerate cases of the application, $\mathbf{J}_0$ will be nonsingular and your $\mathbf{A}$ symmetric PSD.  On the basis that I am dealing with an ellipsoid then indeed the radius does not make sense.  In that case what I am trying to establish is the maximum/minimum distance of any point on the boundary of the hypersurface from its centre, which, if I understand you correctly, will be provided by the eigenvalues?

Comment: Not literally. You have to apply the Spectral Theorem and get new coordinates in which the quadratic becomes $\sum \lambda_jy_j^2 = c$.

Comment: Thank you, I will investigate further.